# fabric.js push() not working when trying to call it using external javaScript

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm new to fabric.js. I'm trying simple example in this page. "Custom background image" 
http://fabricjs.com/customization/

it's working without error when I code it as Internal Javascript. But when I trying to use same code using External JavaScript. It says.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

HTML file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="fabric.js"></script>
    <script src="design.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="canvas_div">
    <canvas id="c" width="300" height="300">
    </canvas>
    </div>

     <script>

        /*var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));
        canvas.setOverlayImage('bg.png', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
        this.__canvases.push(canvas);*/

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));
    canvas.setOverlayImage('bg.png', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    this.__canvases.push(canvas);
```

Comment: Where is the js written? Make sure the file is linked after fabric.js

Comment: code inside "design.js", It's linked after fabric.js

Comment: I found the answer you have to call the fabric.js library on the header. and external java script for the library should call on the footer.

Answer (score 0):

`this.__canvases` means the demos of fabricjs, So you should comment this line. 
`
      var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas')

```
  canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100, width:100, height: 100 }));
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(this.imgSrc, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
  // this.__canvases.push(canvas)
```

`